# How to inspect a Process Explorer full dump

Tags: process-explorer, dump, windbg

I've been having some trouble with Visual Studio 2010. It stops working, and I see it increases in memory usage. So I suspect a memory leak (in one of the plugins maybe). I took a Full Dump with Process Explorer (procexp.exe), but am a bit at loss of what to do with it.

I tried loading it in WinDbg (through File > Open Crash Dump), but get an error 'Symbol file could not be found'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Making dump files is easy, but what do you do with them afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check this out for more information: https://www.networkworld.com/article/2320271/how-to-solve-windows-system-crashes-in-minutes.html

Comment: Thanks. Although the article is about debugging dump from driver errors, I was able to follow it for my VS2010 crash. Together with this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) I loaded in the SOS.DLL and could retrieve the necessary info.

Comment: Please add the actual content of the answer, not just a link.